# Undo disabling pip cache

Tags: python, caching, lambda, pip, serverless-framework

I accidentally ran pip with the `--no-cache-dir` option. Now i'm running into the following error message when I try and deploy a serverless project.

`The directory '/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Uc5FLI/unroll/`

Is there a way to re-enable pip caching?

Answer (score 2):

You have run `sudo -H pip install`; `sudo` ran `pip` as root and `pip` changed ownership of some files and directories under your home dir. Take the files back:

```
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME
```